# Color animation not working

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, silverlight, animation

I have a button named "b", which background I want to change from black to white, but it doesn't work.

The error:

> 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation' animation object cannot be used to animate property 'Background' because it is of incompatible type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'.

My code:

```
Dim changeColor As New Animation.ColorAnimation

changeColor.From = Colors.Black
changeColor.To = Colors.White
changeColor.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2)

Animation.Storyboard.SetTarget(changeColor, b)
Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(changeColor, New PropertyPath(BackgroundProperty))

Dim sb As New Animation.Storyboard
sb.Children.Add(changeColor)
sb.Begin()
```

Have any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Background is of type Brush which cannot be animated with a ColorAnimaion. However, SolidColorBrush has a Color property, so you can do something like:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(changeColor, new PropertyPath("Background.Color"));
```

Comment: Actually it's working! I didn't wrote in correct casing. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 21):

It's worth noting that the same problem can be addressed in XAML using an expression of form:

```
<ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" From="Black" To="White"
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
      Storyboard.TargetName="Body" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this code - it seems whilst I needed to set the Target Property correctly I also had to add a default background color to my Border